# Which subversive connector discovery to use

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive

After I installed the SVN plugin in Eclipse and restarted it, a message appeared asking to install a connector. There are SVN Kit and Native JavaHL connectors. I am confused which one to install and why, can any one please guide me.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The two connectors should both work, here are the differences (more from experience by using them, not by reading their source code):

- SVN Kit:

  - Works on all platforms, is a Java-only implementation (no need for DLLs or shared libraries).
  - Is a little bit slower than JavaHL Native.
  - Keeps its configuration at some other place than a real subversion client like TortoiseSVN (on windows). So if you need both, you have to keep that in mind.
- JavaHL Native:

  - Needs a shared library (DLL), that has the same major version as the installed Subversion client. So if you use SVN command client 1.6.x, you should install / use the corresponding JavaHL version.
  - Is easy to use under Windows, more difficult to find the right version for Linux or Mac OS X (see [Subclipse Wiki: JavaHL](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL)
  - Is faster and uses the same configuration as the installed SVN command client or TortoiseSVN client.

So you may install both, and switch between them under `Windows > Preferences > Team > SVN > SVN Connector`. I have used both and did not notice much difference in my normal word, only in special circumstances. If JavaHL fits in, it is the better connector in my opinion.

Comment: It seems that I am unable to install both SVN Kit 1.7 and JavaHL Native 1.7. Eclipse reports that it cannot do it. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: How about discribe your problem in greater detail, perhaps as another question here? The world has changed, and perhaps we have to re-evaluate what are the rules now?