# Eclipse Subversive, one commit, multiple revision numbers

Tags: eclipse, svn, revision, subversive

I got multiple projects in the same repository location.
If I commit changes to multiple projects in one commit (select them all, and commit), Subversive creates one revision per project.

For example, if I made changes to 17 files in 5 projects, and I commit them all, Subversive will create 5 revisions with the same comment, but what I really want is one revision with the 17 files.

Is there a way to do this with Subversive?

Comment: Subclipse has no problem creating one revision on a multi-project commit.

Comment: @Robert Have you tried it in Eclipse, using the Subversive plugin? Maybe it is something is the default settings. It is happening to me. I have looked into the svn history, and I can "duplicated" entries for the same commit. It only happens when the commit is on multiple projects.

Comment: I don't use Subversive - too many bad experieneces in the past.

Comment: @Robert Would you mind tell me what problems you got in the past? I was using Subclipse before I switched to Subversive, just want to see if it is any better. I don't find any major problem with Subversive, so I hope I can fix the revision problem.

Answer (score 3):

I also have noticed the same behavior if I commit multiple projects in one commit. This apparently happens because of the `JavaHL` svn connector, as mentioned [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/3763/). You could switch to `SVNKit` if this bothers you.

Note, only `JavaHL` enables you to use `Subversive` and other svn clients like `Tortoise SVN` interchangeable for commits on the same files. Here is more detailed [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703377/which-subversive-connector-discovery-to-use) about the difference between `JavaHL` and `SVNKit`.